# Are pushed notifications to mobile phones really pushed?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, push-notification

I know that notifications can be pushed to servers using http/s but can mobile phones really be pushed to from those servers? Technically it is my guess that mobile devices actually poll the notifications servers to see if there are any new notifications and that this is a sort of 'pseudo push'.

So that's my question - do mobile phones truly receive live, pushed notifications or are they actually polling? The reason I ask is that it would seem to be incredibly expensive on the network for mobile phones to have a constantly open channel to masts as a user moves around. Anyone know what the technical detail is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple Push Notifications are delivered to the device over a TCP connection.  The iOS device initiates a TCP connection on [port 5223](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT203609) (with a fallback to 443 on WiFi if 5223 cannot be reached).

Once the TCP session is established very little traffic is required to keep the TCP connection alive - just an occasional keep-alive packet.

When a push notification is to be delivered, the Apple servers look for an existing connection to the device.  If a connection is found then the data stream is sent over the already established connection, so in that sense it is a "push".

If there is no existing connection to the target device then the message is held on the Apple server until the device connects (or the message expires), so at this level it is more like a "pull" - with the device initiating the connection when it can.

I imagine GCM works in a similar way.

Answer (score 0):

There is simply a TCP socket waiting in accept mode on a cloud Google server. The TCP connection had been initiated by the Goggle Play application. That's why Google Play must be installed on the device for making Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) (formerly Android Cloud to Device Messaging Service - C2DM) work.

When this TCP client socket receives some message, the message contains information such as the package name of the application it should be addressed to, and of course - the data itself. This data is parsed and packed into an intent that is broadcast and eventually received by the application.

The TCP socket stays open even when the device's radio state turns into "idle" mode. Applications don't have to be running to receive the intents.

More information at http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html

Comment: Applications don't have to be running, but *something* does.

Comment: Nothing has to be running actually, system will send Broadcast which will wake up your application.

Comment: @Than: *Something* on the phone has to be running in order to receive that broadcast and respond to it.  Put it this way, if your phone is switched off, it won't receive the broadcast.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Correct. Your phone needs to be in an idle or on state. Although if your phone is not connected to a network and the broadcast fails to send then it will be sent again upon reconnecting.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question, though, which is about whether the phone is polling (at the hardware/communication-stack level, implicitly).  (Although the question is actually off-topic for SO...)

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Yes of course, but what i meant is that the Android OS handles everything and will notify you when neccessay (thus the only thing needed is OS, but if we want to go deeper into internal implementation so yes, probably there is special process just for that). Which is the opposite to handling the BLE scan, where you have to provide your own scanning service because.